# Add user with no Microsoft account to VSTS organisation

Tags: azure-devops

I've created a new organization in VSTS and I've created a new project with git repository. I've invited a new user- myself but with a different email, no Microsoft email e.g. john.smith@test.com. By Microsoft email, I mean @hotmail.com or @outlook.com.
I received an invitation an when I tried to enter the organization I received an HTTP 401 response:

```
401 Not Authorized

The VSTS organization you are trying to access only allows Microsoft Accounts. 
Please create a Microsoft Account with a different email 
address and ask your administrator to invite the new Microsoft Account.
```

At work, I use my companies email to log into the VSTS. 
The question is what should I do to add a new user with an email address different than @outlook.com or "hotmail.com to the VSTS repository and be able to see and manage the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VSTS Account is not backed by Azure AD, you must use Microsoft Account to sign in. If you want to use work account to sign in, [connect your VSTS Account to AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-aad?view=vsts).

Comment: Very good and useful tutorial I've fixed the problem in less than 20minutes thanks to the video tutorial ;) Ta!